# set a value to file input using extension

Tags: javascript, file-upload, input, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to upload images to facebook automatically.  So I thought that the best way to do that is using a chrome extension. 
.
I know i cant use javascript to set the value of an input with the type ="file" due to security reasons. 
.
The question is how to make that through chrome extension (No worries about security issues ) .im using the developer mode on Google Chrome 
.i tried this but it didn't work at all: "disable web security and set the value manually through javascript".

.
If it's not possible using extension  .what is the best way to upload files from my server to fb. 
Any answers or comments are appreciated. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Well, it's possible to automate externally with AutoHotKey: `click` at a predefined position relative to the Chrome window that clicks the upload button, paste the file path, `send {Enter}` and submit via Ctrl-Enter `send ^{Enter}`. You can add `sleep 100` between the commands for reliability. Or use Selenium ChromeDriver to control the browser properly.

Comment: Thanks.  I will give it a try and reply afterwards